# python/matplotlib - parasite twin axis scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Trying to plot a spectrum, ie, velocity versus intensity, with lower x axis = velocity, on the upper twin axis = frequency

The relationship between them (doppler formula) is

```
f = (1-v/c)*f_0
```

where f is the resulting frequency, v the velocity, c the speed of light, and f_0 the frequency at v=0, ie. the v_lsr.

I have tried to solve it by looking at  http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/axes_grid/parasite_simple2.html , where it is solved by

```
pm_to_kms = 1./206265.*2300*3.085e18/3.15e7/1.e5
aux_trans = matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().scale(pm_to_kms, 1.)
ax_pm = ax_kms.twin(aux_trans)
ax_pm.set_viewlim_mode("transform")
```

my problem is, how do I replace the pm_to_kms with my function for frequency?

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was:

```
ax_hz = ax_kms.twiny()
x_1, x_2 = ax_kms.get_xlim()
# i want the frequency in GHz so, divide by 1e9
ax_hz.set_xlim(calc_frequency(x_1,data.restfreq/1e9),calc_frequency(x_2,data.restfreq/1e9))
```

This works perfect, and much less complicated solution.

**EDIT : Found a very fancy answer.**
**EDIT2 : Changed the transform call according to the comment by @u55**

This basically involves defining our own conversion/transform. Because of the excellent AstroPy Units equivalencies, it becomes even easier to understand and more illustrative.

```
from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
import astropy.constants as co
import astropy.units as un
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('ggplot')
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.parasite_axes import SubplotHost 


class Freq2WavelengthTransform(mtransforms.Transform): 
    input_dims = 1 
    output_dims = 1 
    is_separable = False 
    has_inverse = True 

    def __init__(self):
        mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)

    def transform_non_affine(self, fr): 
        return (fr*un.GHz).to(un.mm, equivalencies=un.spectral()).value 

    def inverted(self): 
        return Wavelength2FreqTransform() 

class Wavelength2FreqTransform(Freq2WavelengthTransform): 
    input_dims = 1 
    output_dims = 1 
    is_separable = False 
    has_inverse = True 

    def __init__(self):
        mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)

    def transform_non_affine(self, wl): 
        return (wl*un.mm).to(un.GHz, equivalencies=un.spectral()).value 

    def inverted(self): 
        return Freq2WavelengthTransform() 



aux_trans = mtransforms.BlendedGenericTransform(Wavelength2FreqTransform(), mtransforms.IdentityTransform()) 

fig = plt.figure(2) 

ax_GHz = SubplotHost(fig, 1,1,1) 
fig.add_subplot(ax_GHz) 
ax_GHz.set_xlabel("Frequency (GHz)") 


xvals = np.arange(199.9, 999.9, 0.1) 

# data, noise + Gaussian (spectral) lines
data = np.random.randn(len(xvals))*0.01 + np.exp(-(xvals-300.)**2/100.)*0.5 + np.exp(-(xvals-600.)**2/400.)*0.5

ax_mm = ax_GHz.twin(aux_trans) 
ax_mm.set_xlabel('Wavelength (mm)') 
ax_mm.set_viewlim_mode("transform") 
ax_mm.axis["right"].toggle(ticklabels=False) 

ax_GHz.plot(xvals, data) 
ax_GHz.set_xlim(200, 1000) 

plt.draw() 
plt.show()
```

This now produces the desired results:
[image]

Comment: This happened to work correctly, by chance, because the conversion equation between frequency and wavelength (νλ = c) is symmetric with respect to exchange of frequency and wavelength. However, for general transforms, this will give incorrect results.

You should replace `Freq2WavelengthTransform()` with `Wavelength2FreqTransform()` in  the line:
`aux_trans = mtransforms.BlendedGenericTransform(Freq2WavelengthTransform(), mtransforms.IdentityTransform())`.

Answer (score 0):

Your "linear function" is a "simple scaling law" (with an offset). Just replace the `pm_to_kms` definition with your function.

Comment: well yes...

so you mean that I do two transforms, one scaling and one translation?
like
kms_to_deltafreq = -f0/c
deltafreq_to_freq = f0
matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().scale(kms_to_deltafreq, 1.).translate(deltafreq_to_freq,1)
ax_freq = ax_kms.twin(aux_trans)
ax_freq.set_viewlim_mode("transform")

??

Comment: So an answer for now exists here : http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Dual-x-axes-with-transformation-td10865.html if time permits, I will write a proper one here.