# Adjusting y-axis scale in PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a PyPlot script that shows multiple plots. One of the plots (gpu) I wanted to scale down so I will see it in the lower part of the graph (as in the picture). In order to achieve this I set the axis ylim to 300.

```
if ymax is not None:
    ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[0], ymax)
```

The problem is that it messed up to lower ylim, and it is no longer in line with the rest of the axes. Any idea how I can fix that? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python/matplotlib - parasite twin axis scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148808/python-matplotlib-parasite-twin-axis-scaling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because matplotlib by default adds a 5% margin to the data limits on the axes (since the [style changes in `matplotlib` v2.0](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html?highlight=changes%20default%20style#auto-limits)).

Let's say your data limits were `0` – `100`, matplotlib would have added 5% on the top and bottom, so the axis limits would have been `-5` – `105`.

In your case, you have changed the upper limit to `300`, but not modified the lower margin.

So, you probably want to set the limits to `-15` – `315`, to be consistent with the others twin axes.

Note: Of course this relies on you using the default for `ax.margins`. If you have modified that (e.g. by setting `ax.margins` or using the `rcParam` `axes.ymargin`), you need to modify the answer above with the relevant margin.